# Attributes on protocol buffer generated types

Tags: json, serialization, deserialization, protocol-buffers

I have some C# classes generated by protoc, in project A. I'm consuming these classes in project B. Project B serializes/deserializes to JSON using Newtonsoft.Json (for CosmosDB). There's currently an issue in the microsoft.azure.documentdb.core 1.9.1 release which prevents controlling the (de)serialization of models with any method except decorating the model properties with attributes (e.g JsonProperty). In short, I need Newtonsoft.Json to use camel casing for property names and the only way I can do that (that I know of) is to decorate the generated protocol buffer models with `[JsonProperty("myProp")]`.

The types are fairly large and I'd rather not do this manually if possible. My hope is there's a way to tell protoc to generate the classes with custom attributes on the properties?

Comment: Would this help? https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategyCamelCase.htm - it instructs Newtonsoft.Json to use camel case without any code changes...

Comment: @MarcGravell that would be ideal but Cosmos DB DocumentClient won't honor custom JsonSerializerSettings. https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/351

Comment: OK, sorry about that :(

Comment: @MarcGravell no worries, very much appreciate the suggestion. Any other ideas?

Comment: well... you could change the code generator? option 1: edit the `protoc` source, which is C/C++ IIRC; option 2: *if you're not hugely invested in the exact choice of serializer* : protobuf-net's .proto tooling is in C# and would be pretty easy to edit - (but: it has some different API surfaces) - somewhere around here: https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/src/protobuf-net.Reflection/CSharpCodeGenerator.cs#L427